# Modify axis size when using gap.plot

Tags: r, plotrix

I am creating a plot with axes breaks using the package `plotrix`, but the standard `cex.axis` does not seem to work when I build a `gap.plot`.

Do you know how to proceed to modify the size of the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `cex.axis` using the `par` command, you can modify the size of the magnification for axis annotation:

```
library(plotrix)

twogrp <- c(rnorm(5)+4,rnorm(5)+20,rnorm(5)+5,rnorm(5)+22)
gpcol <- c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)

par(cex.axis=2, cex.lab=1.5)
gap.plot(twogrp, gap=c(8,16), xlab="Index", ylab="Group values",
  main="Gap on Y axis", col=gpcol)
```

[image]